# How to change the default marker of itemize environment globally

Tags: lists, memoir, itemize

I was wondering how can I set globally `itemize` lists to use dashes instead of bullets using the `memoir` class. Right now I have to always do:

```
\begin{itemize}[-]
...
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: what about the `enumitem` package?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `\renewcommand` to change the default behavior of the `itemize` environment:

```
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{--}
```

But if you do this for one level, you'll want to do it for all levels  For example:

```
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{+}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{$\circ$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiv}{$\bullet$}
```

The best place to do this would be in your preamble.

Comment: Possibly `\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{---}` (in the preamble).